# Get Subscriber ID with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ampscript, list

When I use the SOAP API to find a subscriber I get a stdClass return with some attribures like Subscriberkey, EmailAddress for each subscriber, but i also get a ID.

```
  "PartnerKey": "",
  "CreatedDate": "2015-07-28T02:54:00",
  "ID": 1486947003,
  "ObjectID": null,
  "EmailAddress": "test@test.com",
```

If I want to merge this ID in an email through AMPscript, is this possible? Because I cant find it in the Profile Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, that was way too easy...

```
%%SubscriberID%%
```

Its just not on the list, but can be reached this way..

Comment: Checkout [Marketing Cloud Personalization Strings](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) for long list of AMPscript personalization strings.